# How to make an internal header when using interface + templates for dependency injection

Tags: c++11, templates, dependency-injection, interface

In this [blog post](https://vladris.com/blog/2016/07/06/dependency-injection-in-c.html) about dependency injection in C++, the author explain a hybrid approach that uses both templates and interfaces as follows:

ICar.h (publicly visible):

```
#pragma once

struct ICar
{
    virtual void Drive() = 0;
    virtual ~ICar() = default;
};

std::unique_ptr<ICar> MakeV8Car();
std::unique_ptr<ICar> MakeV6Car();
```

Car.h (internal):

```
#pragma once
#include "ICar.h"

template <typename TEngine>
class Car : public ICar
{
public:
    void Drive() override
    {
        m_engine.Start();
        // drive
        m_engine.Stop();
    }

private:
    TEngine m_engine;
};
```

Car.cpp:

```
#include "Car.h"
#include "V8Engine.h"
#include "V6Engine.h"

std::unique_ptr<ICar> MakeV8Car()
{
    return std::make_unique<Car<V8Engine>>();
}

std::unique_ptr<ICar> MakeV6Car();
{
    return std::make_unique<Car<V6Engine>>();
}
```

All of which makes good sense to me, except for the internal part.  Let's assume I've created a shared object from the above.

How is `Car.h` private in the context of this shared object?

I've read on the meaning of a `private` header in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2272772/1158977) which states:

```
Keep your data in MyClassPrivate and distribute MyClass.h.
```

Presumably meaning to `not` distribute `MyClass_p.h`, but how does one avoid distributing a header file and still have the `.so` work?

Comment: It just means that clients of your final `.so` library only ever need to see `ICar.h` to be able to work with your code. So when you distribute your code, just package up the `.so` and `ICar.h`.

Comment: I guess I thought by loading the `.so`, then they'll be able to import `Car.h` directly since it's part of the `so`.  Now that I think about it,that's why Linux has `-dev` packages, right?

Comment: Not at all. An `.so` (and `.dll`) only contains binary executable code. I presume it would be very difficult to retrieve a usable `.h` file out of them. That's why you have to package up the `.h` files that the client needs.