# How to make C++ header file use 3rd party headers while only exposing a limited API when said headers are included in the src folder CMakeLists file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, glfw, vulkan

This is my first larger-scale project using CMake, so please bear with me because I might be going about this wrong.

I have the following code, to open a `GLFWwindow`, and start setting up a `VkInstance` with Vulkan. My problem is that this version works fine,
but I can use GLFW components from the EngineDemo.cpp file. This is due to `GameEngine/VulkanEngine/Renderer/src/CMakeLists.txt` including the `glfw3.h`
file as a `PUBLIC` header. I would like to know if there is a way to be able to use `glfw3.h` inside `VulkanRenderer.h` without exposing it to the
API consumer `EngineDemo.cpp`. Also, CMake should be able to only give the right release version (Debug, RelWithDebugInfo, Release) of the `glfw3.h` and `glfw3.lib` to
`VulkanRenderer.h`.

I have the Vulkan SDK with all the components (glfw3, glm) installed on this path:
`C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.236.0`
And I have the following structure in a CLion C++ project using CMake and Microsoft's MSVC compiler version 1929:

```
GameEngine
 |-- Libs
 |   |-- Windows
 |   |   |-- DebugBuild
 |   |   |   |-- glfw3
 |   |   |   |   |-- lib
 |   |   |   |   |   |-- glfw3.lib
 |   |   |   |   |-- include
 |   |   |   |   |   |-- glfw3.h
 |   |   |   |   |   |-- glfw3native.h
 |   |   |-- RelWithDebInfoBuild
 |   |   |   |-- ...
 |   |   |-- ReleaseBuild
 |   |   |   |-- ...
 |   |-- Linux (same structure as Windows folder)
 |-- EngineDemo
 |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
 |   |-- include
 |   |   |-- EngineDemo
 |   |   |   |-- empty
 |   |-- src
 |   |   |-- EngineDemo.cpp
 |   |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
 |-- VulkanEngine
 |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
 |   |-- Renderer
 |   |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
 |   |   |-- include
 |   |   |   |-- Renderer
 |   |   |   |   |-- VulkanRenderer.h
 |   |   |-- src
 |   |   |   |-- VulkanRenderer.cpp
 |   |   |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
 |-- CMakeLists.txt
```

`GameEngine/CMakeLists.txt` content:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(VulkanEngine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(DEBUG_WIN32_LIB_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libs/Windows/DebugBuild")
set(RELEASE_WITH_DEB_INFO_WIN32_LIB_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libs/Windows/RelWithDebInfoBuild")
set(RELEASE_WIN32_LIB_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libs/Windows/ReleaseBuild")

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    set(GLFW3_INCLUDE_PATH "${DEBUG_WIN32_LIB_PATH}/glfw3/include")
    set(GLFW3_LIB_PATH "${DEBUG_WIN32_LIB_PATH}/glfw3/lib/glfw3.lib")

    if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
        # using GCC
    elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")
        # using Visual Studio C++
        add_definitions(-D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2)
    endif()

elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "RelWithDebInfo")
    set(GLFW3_INCLUDE_PATH "${RELEASE_WITH_DEB_INFO_WIN32_LIB_PATH}/glfw3/include")
    set(GLFW3_LIB_PATH "${RELEASE_WITH_DEB_INFO_WIN32_LIB_PATH}/glfw3/lib/glfw3.lib")

    if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
        # using GCC
    elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")
        # using Visual Studio C++
        add_definitions(-D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0)
    endif()

elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    set(GLFW3_INCLUDE_PATH "${RELEASE_WIN32_LIB_PATH}/glfw3/include")
    set(GLFW3_LIB_PATH "${RELEASE_WIN32_LIB_PATH}/glfw3/lib/glfw3.lib")

    if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
        # using GCC
    elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")
        # using Visual Studio C++
        add_definitions(-D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0)
    endif()
endif()

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("VulkanEngine")
add_subdirectory ("EngineDemo")
```

`GameEngine/EngineDemo/CMakeLists.txt` content:

```cmake
add_subdirectory(src)
```

`GameEngine/EngineDemo/src/CMakeLists.txt` content:

```cmake
project(EngineDemo)

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} EngineDemo.cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ../include)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC VulkanEngineModule)
```

`GameEngine/EngineDemo/src/EngineDemo.cpp` content:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Renderer/VulkanRenderer.h"

int main()
{
    VulkanRenderer app;

    try {
        app.run();
    } catch (const std::exception &exception) {
        std::cerr << exception.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`GameEngine/VulkanEngine/CMakeLists.txt` content:

```cmake
add_subdirectory(Renderer)
```

`GameEngine/VulkanEngine/Renderer/CMakeLists.txt` content:

```cmake
add_subdirectory(src)
```

`GameEngine/VulkanEngine/Renderer/include/Renderer/VulkanRenderer.h` content:

```cpp
#pragma once

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include "glfw3.h"

class VulkanRenderer {
private:
    VkInstance vkInstance;
    GLFWwindow* window = nullptr;
public:
    void run();
private:
    void initWindow();
    void initVulkan();
    void mainLoop();
    void cleanup();
    void createVulkanInstance();
};
```

`GameEngine/VulkanEngine/Renderer/src/CMakeLists.txt` content:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.24)
project(VulkanEngineModule)

add_library (${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC VulkanRenderer.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ../include)


find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)

if(Vulkan_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE ${Vulkan_LIBRARIES})
endif(Vulkan_FOUND)

if(WIN32)
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${GLFW3_INCLUDE_PATH})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE ${GLFW3_LIB_PATH})
endif(WIN32)
```

`GameEngine/VulkanEngine/Renderer/src/VulkanRenderer.cpp` content:

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#endif

#include "Renderer/VulkanRenderer.h"

void VulkanRenderer::run() {
    initWindow();
    initVulkan();
    mainLoop();
    cleanup();
}

void VulkanRenderer::initWindow() {
    const uint32_t WIDTH = 800;
    const uint32_t HEIGHT = 600;
    const char* WINDOW_TITLE = "Vulkan Engine";
    glfwInit();
    VkInstance c;
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, WINDOW_TITLE, nullptr, nullptr);
}

void VulkanRenderer::initVulkan() {
    createVulkanInstance();
}

void VulkanRenderer::mainLoop() {
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

void VulkanRenderer::cleanup() {
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
}

void VulkanRenderer::createVulkanInstance() {
    VkApplicationInfo appInfo{};
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
    appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;
}
```

If I move the `VkInstance` and `GLFWwindow` declarations and the `glfw3.h` header include macro to the `VulkanRenderer.cpp` file
with the `#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN` alongside it and change the `target_include_directories` to `PRIVATE` for the `GLFW_INCLUDE_PATH` in `GameEngine/VulkanEngine/Renderer/src/CMakeLists.txt`
an empty window opens when I run the `EngineDemo.exe`; this does not expose lower-level functions to `EngineDemo.cpp` either. But this is not the goal.
I would like to declare every member variable of the `VulkanRenderer` class in the corresponding header file.

I tried to change `GameEngine/VulkanEngine/Renderer/include/Renderer/VulkanRenderer.h` to this:

```cpp
#pragma once

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include "Renderer/glfw_config.h"

class VulkanRenderer {
private:
    VkInstance vkInstance;
    GLFWwindow* window = nullptr;
public:
    void run();
private:
    void initWindow();
    void initVulkan();
    void mainLoop();
    void cleanup();
    void createVulkanInstance();
};
```

Added a `glfw_config.h.in` file to the `GameEngine/VulkanEngine/Renderer/src` folder that looked like this:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "@GLFW3_INCLUDE_PATH@/glfw3.h"
```

Appended these two lines to the end of `GameEngine/VulkanEngine/Renderer/src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glfw_config.h.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../include/Renderer/glfw_config.h" @ONLY)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../include")
```

The resulting `glfw_config.h` file in `GameEngine/cmake-build-debug-visual-studio/VulkanEngine/Renderer/include/Renderer` has the following content:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "C:/Projects/GameEngine/Libs/Windows/DebugBuild/glfw3/include/glfw3.h"
```

The above path to the header file is the correct one, and this works just like the previous setup.
If this line `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../include")` changes to `INTERFACE` or `PRIVATE` then `Renderer/glfw_config.h` cannot be found.

My idea was that if I generate the proper `glfw_config.h` header file with the appropriate absolute path when reloading the CMake project, I would be able to
finally, use `glfw3.h` in all different run configurations from the `VulkanRenderer.h` header file and not expose it to the outside world if I set the above-mentioned visibility to `INTERFACE` or `PRIVATE`.

Is there a way to automatically generate this `#include` path with CMake depending on which release I am building my project on and to only keep the GLFW components found in `glfw3.h` and by extension, all components in `vulkan.h` inside the `GameEngine/VulkanEngine` project only, and expose a limited API to the `EngineDemo` project?

If this is not possible with just the use of CMake, I would also greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to restructure the project the achieve the desired effect.

I tried googling for a similar question already, but the automatic system of StackOverflow didn't detect any duplicates either.

Comment: Good job on being detailed, but I wonder if you're being too detailed. `ctrl+f` of your current question body, there's only one question mark, and that paragraph seems like it could be asked as a generalized quesiton without most of the context you have provided. Do you think so? Or have I misunderstood (very likely since I was lazy and tl;dr)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, first of all.
Yes, that question would cover the general problem, but I don't know if what I am asking is even possible to do with CMake. That is why I provided the context with the project structure and this MWE code base, in case someone can attack this from another angle.

That is also the reason why I am open to project restructuring suggestions.

Comment: Hm. I might suggest creating a post where you try making it as abstracted away from your specific context as possible and just ask how to implement what include path logic and macro definitions or whatnot would solve your problem. You don't need to delete this post to do that. If you do, just [edit] this one to also link to the more abstracted one.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I managed to find a solution that would work for my case.

Comment: Well done, and thanks for writing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for a day to formulate a more generic question and researching for it, I found out about a new use case for header files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272735/private-public-header-example).

This seems to work perfectly well in my application when the `VkInstance` and `GLFWwindow *` are declared in the private header instead of the public one.
When the private header is the one that has these macros:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include "glfw3.h"
```

I can still easily control the propagation of the 3rd party header files with CMake to higher levels on the dependency graph.